# Clicking Edit button on first record in view does not Get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with 2 buttons as follows:

```
<td>
  <div style="float: left; width: auto;">
    <%= button_to 'Edit', edit_jobitem_path(:id => p.id), :method => :get %>
  </div>
 <%= button_to 'Destroy', p, :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</td>
```

Both buttons work fine, with one very strange exception: The Edit button on the first record Posts (the parent Jobs record) instead of Gets (the child JobItems record).

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= button_to 'Edit', edit_jobitem_path(p), method: :get %>
```

If this doesn't set the correct `method`, you'll *probably* have an issue with JQuery not being loaded on your app.

Without that extra context, I can only suggest that you try the above and if it doesn't work, you should post your layout and the request log.

Comment: That didn't work (changing to what you wrote). Note that if I use link_to, it links correctly. It is just the button_to, and only on the first record. And as I said before, it doesn't post the jobitem, it posts the parent job, strangely.